# mooWMD is Undefined?

Tags: javascript, mootools, wysiwyg, wmd

First off here is the code!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href="content/wmd.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>some title </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <form>
            <h2>Only teaxt area</h2>
            <div id="wmd-editor-uno" class="wmd-panel">
                <div id="wmd-button-bar-uno" class='wmd-button-bar'></div>
                <textarea name='id-uno' id='id-uno'></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="Scripts/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="Scripts/moowmd.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var MyConfig = [
        {
            input: 'id-uno',
            postfix: '-uno'
         }];
         window.addEvent('domready', function() {
             window.MyMooWMD = new mooWMD.WMD(window.MyConfig);
             window.MyMooWMD.start();
         });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Bam!

My problem is this, it doesn't work like the example at [mooWMD tutorial](http://moowmd.awardspace.info/moowmd-tutorial.html) all I get is an empty text area with the wmd.css style applied to it. I cant figure out what I could be doing wrong. All the file locations are correct but i get 'mooWMD' is undefined. I am at a loss any and all suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: make 100% sure that you have the right src path

Comment: @Aaron: I've check the mooWMD tutorial and opened the Demo Page link. Their example gives the exact same error (using IE 8). Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: The Demo page works on all my browsers but I downloaded that page and got the same error I described. I have even copied and pasted all the java script from moowmd.js into the same page as the textarea and got the same area. I am 100% sure its not pathing.

Comment: oohh, if I turn on compatibility mode on the demo page it breaks the page and I get the same error I am getting in development.. I wounder what is going on there.

Comment: They say: "Beware! WMD uses images, make sure the paths in the CSS to the images directory are correct!". Is your path to the images directory correct?

Comment: Yes, I used Firebug and inspected the wmd.css all images where found.

Comment: Funnily enough, I'm not using compatiblity mode in IE and the demo page still breaks regardless. Maybe we're missing something obvious. :P

Comment: It is odd, the demo page no longer works for me in IE 8 with or with out the compatibility mode. It still works in Firefox. Magically my dev test page is now working in Firefox as well. Perhaps the answer is use a different version of WMD.

Comment: It's possible, maybe you're missing the latest version of mootools-yui-compressed.js. Then again, on the demo page it's loaded directly from api.google.com. I know this may sound silly or unrelated, but remove the xmlns attribute from your <html> tag, I've seen it mess up layouts badly sometimes.

Comment: nope, I am now 90% certain the problem is the control and not the way I am using it. But thank you I really thought it was me before you said you where having problems with it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (for later generations) is IE does not accepts the following syntax:

```
{
   att1: 'value',
   att2: 'value'
}
```

Where other browsers do.
I changed it to

```
{
   'att1': 'value',
   'att2': 'value'
}
```

And it is fine now.
(using the mailing list would have gotten my attention earlier)

Comment: I downloaded the newest version and applied this change and it works. You Rock! This saves me a lot of time I have been trying to get Stackoverflow's branch to work with multiple instances on a page.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the local javascript tag executes as soon as the tag is processed. This may happen before moowmd.js has completed loading.

Wrap the code in a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loaded() {
        var MyConfig = [
        {
            input: 'id-uno',
            postfix: '-uno'
         }];
         window.addEvent('domready', function() {
             window.MyMooWMD = new mooWMD.WMD(window.MyConfig);
             window.MyMooWMD.start();
         });}
</script>
```

Then add an onload handler to your body tag:

```
    <body onload="loaded();">
```

The onload handler will not fire until all the javascript, images, css, etc have loaded.

Comment: I had high hopes for this... but nope.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <head>
       <title>some title </title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/wmd.css" />
       <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/showdown.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div id="wmd-editor" class="wmd-panel">
                <div id="wmd-button-bar">
                </div>
                <textarea id="wmd-input"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel">
            </div>
            <div id="wmd-output" class="wmd-panel">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/wmd.js"></script>
    </body>
```

The root of the problem ended up being the moowmd editor just didn't work consistently in IE. The reason I was tiring to go with the moowmd was I liked how he handled setting up multiple editors. I ended up just switching to [stackoverflow's branch](http://github.com/derobins/wmd/tree/master) of wmd it is working well so far.

Comment: Give it another try. IE bugs I could find where fixed.